# Conditionally Aggregate Against Choice of Pairs : Home or Away

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for the best way to aggregate soccer matches into an aggregate table to display qualification table. I have data that looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f4fb"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be8"),
    "homeGoals" : 4,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-28T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f4fd"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be9"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0d"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-29T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f502"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bed"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0f"),
    "homeGoals" : 4,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-05-18T07:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f4fe"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c13"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bee"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-29T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f503"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c1c"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be9"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 3,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e0f42aa4d69585f4fa"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c30"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfe"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-28T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f4ff"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf4"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-29T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f4fc"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bdb"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf6"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-28T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f500"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c2d"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be0"),
    "homeGoals" : 3,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-29T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f504"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf4"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c30"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f501"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c1c"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-25T07:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f505"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be0"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c13"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-05T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 13 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f506"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be0"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bee"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b5"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-11T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 14 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f507"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c13"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c30"),
    "homeGoals" : 3,
    "awayGoals" : 4,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b5"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-12T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 15 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f50c"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be8"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-04T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 16 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f511"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be0"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf4"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-23T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 17 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f516"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be9"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b5"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-12T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 18 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f50a"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c13"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0f"),
    "homeGoals" : 4,
    "awayGoals" : 3,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-25T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 19 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f50b"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bdb"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-04T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 20 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f51b"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be8"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf6"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-05T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 21 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f50f"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bee"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c1c"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b5"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-13T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 22 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f520"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-19T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 23 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f514"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfe"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-05T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 24 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f510"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0d"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be0"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-19T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 25 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f519"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf6"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c30"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 3,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-25T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 26 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f515"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c2d"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0f"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b5"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-10T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 27 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f51e"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be8"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b5"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-12T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 28 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f51a"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c2d"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfe"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-27T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 29 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f51f"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c30"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bdb"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-17T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 30 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f508"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfe"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c13"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-19T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 31 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f50d"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bee"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-06T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 32 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f512"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-26T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 33 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f517"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0f"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "homeGoals" : 4,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-18T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 34 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f51c"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0f"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bdb"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-04T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 35 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f521"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be9"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-24T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 36 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f509"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bee"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c2d"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-20T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 37 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f50e"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfe"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b5"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-12T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 38 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f513"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0f"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0d"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-04T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 39 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f518"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c1c"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf6"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 3,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-19T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 40 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f51d"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf6"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bed"),
    "homeGoals" : 0,
    "awayGoals" : 4,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b4"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-05T07:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 41 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f522"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bdb"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c1c"),
    "homeGoals" : 6,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b7"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-27T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 42 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f523"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bed"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-05T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 43 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f524"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bdb"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be8"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-11T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 44 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f528"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bed"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be9"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-12T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 45 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f526"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf6"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-11T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 46 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f525"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf4"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c2d"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-22T07:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 47 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f529"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfe"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be0"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-05T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 48 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f52b"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "homeGoals" : 2,
    "awayGoals" : 1,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-12T08:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 49 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f527"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c30"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bee"),
    "homeGoals" : 3,
    "awayGoals" : 0,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-05-03T07:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 50 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e2f42aa4d69585f52a"),
    "home" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be9"),
    "away" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "homeGoals" : 1,
    "awayGoals" : 2,
    "tournament" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff90b"),
    "stage" : ObjectId("59726e597ec27162718ff9b8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-23T07:00:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Home and Away are the IDs of the teams, homeGoals and awayGoals are the score of the match. Those are the main players on the query I need to write. In some matches, Team A is the home team, in others Team A is the away team. But I need to aggregate this table like so:

```
Team   | Games Played | Games Won | Games Lost | Games Drawn | Goals For | Goals Against | Goal Differential | Points
------ | ------------ | --------- | ---------- | ----------- | --------- | ------------- | ----------------- | ------
Team A | 10           | 6         | 3          | 1           | 10        | 3             | 7                 | 21    
Team B | 10           | 5         | 3          | 2           | 11        | 5             | 6                 | 18
```

I need a way to combine Teams by ID, no matter if they are home or away teams, sum up their goals, and calculate the differential.

What would be a good way to achieve this with a mongoose query, without having to query everything and using reduce or something like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you are trying to force MongoDB to act like a relational database, which is evident from the `ObjectId(...)` references everywhere in your document. This is not a natural MongoDB design pattern, and has lead to the difficulty of expressing your requirements in simple terms. I would suggest you to rethink your schema design. For example, if this aggregate result is what you require all the time, you should align your MongoDB schema model to support easy aggregation. See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/ for examples.

Comment: You may have a point there. All I'm really familiar with is SQL DBs. I'll try to rethink the schema. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would "pre-aggregate" the results per team and update them after each match is complete, incrementing each of the counters as appropriate. But there still is nothing structurally wrong here, and it's just a matter of essentially treating "each game" as a separate record for each team.

This is easily done by applying [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to each of the teams, and selecting the appropriate "home" or "away" values according to which one is being processed. So your main "friend" here is the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) "ternary" expression, which allows you to selectively return values:

```
db.games.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "teams": {
      "$map": {
        "input": ["$home","$away"],
        "as": "t",
        "in": {
          "team": "$$t",
          "played": 1,
          "win": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$or": [
                  { "$and": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$$t", "$home" ] },
                    { "$gt": [ "$homeGoals", "$awayGoals" ] }   
                  ]},
                 { "$and": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$$t", "$away" ] },
                   { "$gt": [ "$awayGoals", "$homeGoals" ] }   
                 ]} 
                ]
              },
              "then": 1,
              "else": 0    
            }
          },
          "lost": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$or": [
                  { "$and": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$$t", "$home" ] },
                    { "$lt": [ "$homeGoals", "$awayGoals" ] }   
                  ]},
                 { "$and": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$$t", "$away" ] },
                   { "$lt": [ "$awayGoals", "$homeGoals" ] }   
                 ]} 
                ]
              },
              "then": 1,
              "else": 0    
            }
          },
          "draw": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": ["$homeGoals","$awayGoals"]
              },
              "then": 1,
              "else": 0    
            }
          },
          "goalsFor": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { "$eq": [ "$$t", "$home" ] },
              "then": "$homeGoals",
              "else": "$awayGoals"
            }    
          },
          "goalsAgainst": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { "$eq": [ "$$t", "$away" ] },
              "then": "$homeGoals",
              "else": "$awayGoals"
            }    
          }
        }
      }    
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$teams" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$teams.team",
    "played": { "$sum": "$teams.played" },
    "win": { "$sum": "$teams.win" },
    "lost": { "$sum": "$teams.lost" },
    "draw": { "$sum": "$teams.draw" },
    "goalsFor": { "$sum": "$teams.goalsFor" },
    "goalsAgainst": { "$sum": "$teams.goalsAgainst" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "goalDifferential": {
      "$abs": { 
        "$subtract": [ "$goalsFor", "$goalsAgainst" ]
      }
    },
    "points": {
      "$add": [
        { "$multiply": [ "$win", 3 ] },
        "$draw"  
      ]
    }    
  }},
  { "$sort": { "points": -1, "goalDifferential": 1 } }
])
```

So if you look at that "purely" from the initial [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operation and the different fields being projected in that array, each "game" is going to be transformed into something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5976b6e1f42aa4d69585f4fb"),
    "teams" : [ 
        {
            "team" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
            "played" : 1.0,
            "win" : 1.0,
            "lost" : 0.0,
            "draw" : 0.0,
            "goalsFor" : 4.0,
            "goalsAgainst" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "team" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be8"),
            "played" : 1.0,
            "win" : 0.0,
            "lost" : 1.0,
            "draw" : 0.0,
            "goalsFor" : 1.0,
            "goalsAgainst" : 4.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Which effectively turns each game into "two" sets of results, being a set of results from the perspective of "each team".

From there it's pretty standard fare, where you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array in order to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by each "team" identifier, accumulating the results.

For the additional fields, you can calculate these "after" the grouping has been done, or include them in the initial projection and grouping as appropriate. My interpretation here applies `3` points to a "win" and `1` to each "draw", and then considers the "absolute" difference in order to apply the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) ranking for a leaderboard, and give some separation on those teams with the same "points".

Of course you can do whatever you want, but the main principles here are using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to create an "array" of results for each participating team in each game, and using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to discern between the "home" and "away" and thus record the appropriate values.

The overall results on the sample of 50 games provided includes 18 distinct teams in the output as:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfa"),
    "played" : 7.0,
    "win" : 4.0,
    "lost" : 0.0,
    "draw" : 3.0,
    "goalsFor" : 10.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 6.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 4.0,
    "points" : 15.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c30"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 4.0,
    "lost" : 1.0,
    "draw" : 1.0,
    "goalsFor" : 15.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 9.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 6.0,
    "points" : 13.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf7"),
    "played" : 7.0,
    "win" : 3.0,
    "lost" : 2.0,
    "draw" : 2.0,
    "goalsFor" : 10.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 7.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 3.0,
    "points" : 11.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bdb"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 3.0,
    "lost" : 1.0,
    "draw" : 2.0,
    "goalsFor" : 11.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 4.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 7.0,
    "points" : 11.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0f"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 3.0,
    "lost" : 2.0,
    "draw" : 1.0,
    "goalsFor" : 12.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 12.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 0.0,
    "points" : 10.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be0"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 2.0,
    "lost" : 1.0,
    "draw" : 3.0,
    "goalsFor" : 6.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 5.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 1.0,
    "points" : 9.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bed"),
    "played" : 4.0,
    "win" : 3.0,
    "lost" : 1.0,
    "draw" : 0.0,
    "goalsFor" : 9.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 1.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 8.0,
    "points" : 9.0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c2d"),
    "played" : 5.0,
    "win" : 2.0,
    "lost" : 1.0,
    "draw" : 2.0,
    "goalsFor" : 6.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 5.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 1.0,
    "points" : 8.0
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c21"),
    "played" : 7.0,
    "win" : 2.0,
    "lost" : 3.0,
    "draw" : 2.0,
    "goalsFor" : 6.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 10.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 4.0,
    "points" : 8.0
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf4"),
    "played" : 4.0,
    "win" : 2.0,
    "lost" : 1.0,
    "draw" : 1.0,
    "goalsFor" : 5.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 2.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 3.0,
    "points" : 7.0
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c13"),
    "played" : 5.0,
    "win" : 1.0,
    "lost" : 1.0,
    "draw" : 3.0,
    "goalsFor" : 8.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 8.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 0.0,
    "points" : 6.0
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bfe"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 1.0,
    "lost" : 2.0,
    "draw" : 3.0,
    "goalsFor" : 3.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 4.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 1.0,
    "points" : 6.0
}

/* 13 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bee"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 1.0,
    "lost" : 2.0,
    "draw" : 3.0,
    "goalsFor" : 4.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 7.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 3.0,
    "points" : 6.0
}

/* 14 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be9"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 1.0,
    "lost" : 4.0,
    "draw" : 1.0,
    "goalsFor" : 6.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 8.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 2.0,
    "points" : 4.0
}

/* 15 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314be8"),
    "played" : 5.0,
    "win" : 1.0,
    "lost" : 3.0,
    "draw" : 1.0,
    "goalsFor" : 6.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 10.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 4.0,
    "points" : 4.0
}

/* 16 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314bf6"),
    "played" : 6.0,
    "win" : 1.0,
    "lost" : 4.0,
    "draw" : 1.0,
    "goalsFor" : 7.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 12.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 5.0,
    "points" : 4.0
}

/* 17 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c1c"),
    "played" : 5.0,
    "win" : 0.0,
    "lost" : 3.0,
    "draw" : 2.0,
    "goalsFor" : 2.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 13.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 11.0,
    "points" : 2.0
}

/* 18 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596fe03ad496e047d6314c0d"),
    "played" : 3.0,
    "win" : 0.0,
    "lost" : 2.0,
    "draw" : 1.0,
    "goalsFor" : 1.0,
    "goalsAgainst" : 4.0,
    "goalDifferential" : 3.0,
    "points" : 1.0
}
```

And of course if you want the "team name", then clearly that resides in "another collection" for which you would use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and further operations in order to match the appropriate `ObjectId` value to the other related collection information you wanted in the final output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Neil, I tried to execute your query from Robo 3T, and I get the following error.


`Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "field inclusion is not allowed inside of $expressions",
 "code" : 16420
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: @blacktone If you were paying attention to the output I pasted ( as I did to your input ) then you would have noticed I too ran the whole thing through Robo3T without any error. What is your MongoDB server version? It could possibly be the `"played"` field in the `$map`, which you could do `"played": { "$literal": 1 }` instead. But works fine for me with MongoDB 3.4, In fact if your version is MongoDB at least 3.2 you should not need to change a thing.

Comment: I'm using hosted mLab DB. They use 3.2. But you're saying that it still shouldn't be an issue, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @blacktone You should really be able to simply copy and paste what is here. Like I said I just copied your data in the question and put in into a collection called `"games"`, as is shown. I can check against a 3.2 instance just to be sure, but there is nothing here that should produce that particular error.